# How to handle a main site plus multiple virtualhosts on one server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a standard Ubuntu install. Apache web root is /var/www.

I want to host my "main" site and a handful of others.

Normally I would put the files for mysite.com right in the web root. However, if I want to host multiple sites that seems like it could get messy. It seems like I would end up with a structure like:

My "main" site's files:

```
/var/www/index.html
/var/www/images/
/var/www/js/
```

etc...

and then my virtual sites like:

```
/var/www/somesite/ #somesite's files in here
/var/www/foobar/ #foobar's files in here
```

How should I be organizing such a setup? Mixing files from the main site with directories for virtualhost sites seems wrong and messy. I thought about putting my "main" site into its own directory in the webroot (like "somesite" and "foobar" are above) but then people visiting my IP address would get the web root without any site files in it. Should I do this and then redirect anything to the main IP to the "main" site's dir? Maybe with htaccess? Maybe in the apache configuration somewhere?

How would you approach this?

---

**What I ended up doing** (thanks to the suggestions below, all of which were helpful)...

Here is what the config file (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default`) had originally:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

By changing it to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/mysite/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

I was able to get visits to go to "mysite.com" (I have the public files served out of the `public` directory so I can have some system files up one level and not web accessible)

I then set up another site at next.mysite.com by creating a new config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nextconfig` that looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/next
<Directory "/var/www/next">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerName next.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the "main" site in a subdirectory of `/var/www` as well, and change your Apache configuration to reflect its new location.

Comment: If I do this, how do I handle visits to the document root at /var/www/? Assume my IP is 234.56.78.90. Since a visit to mysite.com will use what is in /var/www/mysite/ but the document root is /var/www/ what happens when someone visits my IP address directly? Do I need to use htaccess to redirect such visits to /var/www/mysite?

Comment: If you don't have a VirtualHost or the main server configured to serve documents from /var/www then nobody will ever see it.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to mix it. Not one bit.

Place the virtual host directory in `/var/vh1` `/var/vh2` and so on. Its not necesary to place all of them in `/var/www`

An example:

```
Listen 80

# This is the "main" server running on 172.20.30.40
ServerName server.domain.com
DocumentRoot /www/mainserver

# This is the other address
NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.50

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here ...

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here ...

</VirtualHost>
```

I took it from [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) page itself. So its pretty reliable.

Comment: You could also look at VirtualDocumentRoot, which is a more flexible variant of DocumentRoot. It allows variables, so you don't have to hardcode a VirtualHost entry for each domain. For example, `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0` would allow you to simply create a new directory /var/www/www.example3.com and it would be served by Apache. Very useful if you often change or create new sites.

Comment: Or you could split it up like `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2.0.%-1` which takes the penultimate and ultimate parts of the domain name, effectively ignoring the subdomain for the path. You'd get `/var/www/domain.com` whether you came in via www.domain.com or domain.com. All depends on what you find useful.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think you should just make a folder `/var/Www/main` for your own site. It's easier to keep track of then.

Just create a virtualhost for your mainsite and point it to the new folder.